# react-konva-utils html is exceeding stage canvas

Tags: react-konva

I tried to use react-konva-utils html but it seems the zorder inside the html is not following the parent element.

Here's the sample screenshot below. As you can see the iframe inside the html is exceeding over the konva stage. Compare to the red box which reside inside the Konva Stage. Here's my code :

```
 <Stage  width={dimensions.width} height={dimensions.height} style={{position :"relative"}}>
  <Layer>
     <Group x={50} y={50} draggable onClick={(e) => itemClick(e)}>
     <Rect x={0} y={0} width={100} height={100} fill="green"  />
      <Html divProps={{ style: { pointerEvents: "none" } }}>
         <div>
            <iframe width="100" height="100"
               src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
              </iframe>        
              </div>      
      </Html>
    </Group>

      <Transformer ref={transformerRef} /> 
  </Layer>
</Stage>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Html />` component is not a native citizen of canvas. It is rendered outside of it. Basically, just on top of the canvas with absolute position.

As the solution, you can try to set `overflow: hidden` style on a parent container.

Comment: It works!! ... One more thing , how do I send to back or send to front that layer from other layers ? lt always stays on top of everyone else. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And also .. is there a way to render youtube video using Konva.Image? I ended up using html because can't seem to find any sample the render youtube videos.